# \polyprint doesn't work properly with brackets?

Tags: polynom

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
  \polyadd\polya{5(6x-7)-4(9-10x)}{0}%
  \polyprint\polya
\end{document}
```

I think the result should be `70x-71` but the result is `70x+1`. I think the `+1` is the result of `5*(-7) + 4*9` (the correct expression is `5*(-7) - 4*9` of course).

Do I something wrong or it's a bug in [polynom](https://ctan.org/pkg/polynom) package?

Comment: Note that `\polyadd\polya{5(6x-7)}{4(10x-9)}` gives the correct result.

Comment: It doesn't help me :( I want create a question ("expand it") and show the (generated) result.

Comment: Workaround: `5(6x-7)+(-4)(9-10x)`

Comment: Indeed. Do you think it's a bug in package? Where can I report it?